# Phaser 3. Importing phaser/src/core/Game produce error during runtime

Tags: html5-canvas, phaser-framework

The phaser game not starting error on

[image]

```
import Game1 from "phaser/src/core/Game";
import { Game } from "phaser";
console.log(Game1, Game);
const app = new Game1(gameSettings);
```

the following output of the console log which are similar class:
[image]

but when I trie to make use the one from the phaser js directly, no error found

```
import { Game } from "phaser";
const app = new Game(gameSettings);
```

Thanks in advance for answers which part I do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In all example I found on the web I see this kind of imports for Phaser

```
import 'phaser';
import Phaser from 'phaser';
import * as Phaser from 'phaser';
```

and then boot the game with

```
new Phaser.Game(config)
```